# MySQL server version for the right syntax group by datetime

Tags: datetime, group-by, syntax-error, date-format

I have been trying to solve the issue to group by datetime for sometimes but I still can't resolve it.
Please give some advice on what wrong with my syntax?

Sytnax error message i get:-

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' DATE_FORMAT(mdatetime,'%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Date',count(*) AS 'Total Registrants' fro' at line 1**

```
select $regdate AS 'Date',count(*) AS 'Total Registrants' from $regTable where $regdate <= '$date' group by $regdate order by $regdate DESC LIMIT 10
```